# Unity3D translates animation on import

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, character

I have an animation problem and I can't figure it out.
I've imported an animated character from Maya 2014 to Unity 4.0 using the Humanoid rig. Everything seems to work fine. The avatar was automatically recognized and the animation works but for some reason the hips won't move!

I have animated a "jumping" run so the character has to go up and down while running. To do this I have animated the translation of the hip bone and for some reason it is not imported in  Unity (the rotation works by the way). So the character is running in mid-air.

What might cause this?

[image]

as you can see the hips should go up and down, but in unity it's not moving

Comment: Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: I would assume one of your import settings to be the problem here. Particularly the root motion Y translation value. That might need to be set to use the original as set in the file. But an example would be nice indeed.

Comment: Please show us your import settings for the animation. Particularly the rigging.

Comment: What if you uncheck "Apply root motion" in the inspector by selecting the character from the hierarchy?

Comment: @Bart 
Here alla my settings: http://s4.postimg.org/celd90st9/Senza_titolo_1.jpg

And i just noticed that if i check "apply root motion" the animation works perfectly but the character start rotating around and that's inconvenient for a side-scrolling game...